# Replacing contents of Tkinter widgets

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I am trying to develop a Twitter-like client to get the hang of tkinter.  I am displaying 7 tweets per screen from tweets stored in an sqlite database.  One line has name, screen name and created date in labels. Under that is a text box with the tweet text.  When the user presses the Next or Previous button I want to display the next or previous 7 tweets from the file.  Not sure how to clear the previous ones and update with the new data.  That is because I want the widget creation to be dynamic as in the code below.  Thus there is no way to address a particular widget my name.

```
 if tweetStr:
    while i <  listLen:   
        print(i)
        user_name = tweetStr[i]['name']
        screen_name = tweetStr[i]['screen_name']
        created = tweetStr[i]['created_at']
        tweet_text = (tweetStr[i]['short_text'] if not tweetStr[i]['long_text'] else tweetStr[i]['long_text'] )

        top_space = tk.Text(f, width= 100, height=1)
        top_space.grid(column = 0, row = start_row,columnspan=6, sticky="nsew")
        top_space.configure(background='lightblue')

        ttk.Label(f, text=user_name).grid(column=0, row=start_row+1,sticky='w')
        ttk.Label(f, text=screen_name).grid(column=1, row=start_row+1,sticky='w')
        ttk.Label(f, text=created).grid(column=2, row=start_row+1,sticky='w')

        t = tk.Text(f, width= 100, height=3, wrap='word')
        t.grid(column = 0, row = start_row+2,columnspan=6, sticky="nsew")
        #t.insert(INSERT, "Begin " + "This is a test " * 800 + " END" + '\n\n')
        t.insert(tk.INSERT, tweet_text)

        i += 1
        start_row += 6
```

Answer (score 0):

For a text widget, use the delete method to remove existing text then use insert to add the new information. Avoid destroying and re-creating widgets all the time. Create them once then update their contents using Text.insert and Label.configure.
I would also avoid the `while` loop in favour of calling a method using `after` until you have processed everything. A tight loop prevents handling events until you complete the whole loop while using after breaks up each iteration of the loop with event processing.

Comment: Notice the labels and text box are created in a loop and not addressable by a variable name, thus I don't see how I can use the delete method.  I only see two options and neither looks good - hopefully there is a third.  Put all the dynamically generated widgets in a named frame and delete the frame, or create 7 sets of widgets all assigned to variable names.

Comment: Thats what classes are for. Create a class based on the Frame widget to manage your collection of widgets. Retain the child widget IDs as members. Basically manage this as a composite widget to simplify the main program code.

Answer (score 0):

The solution turned out to be fairly simple.

```
 for widget in f.winfo_children():
       if isinstance(widget, tk.Text):
            widget.delete('1.0', "end")
       elif isinstance(widget,ttk.Label):
            widget['text'] = ''
```